# Access to /obj/Release/net461/win7-x86/PubTmp/Out/ was denied while publishing web app to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-devops

While publishing to Azure as WebApp it gives me a lot of errors says that i couldn't copy files to Release folder due to access denied

I've tried remove bin and obj folders and rebuld then but it doesn't work for me.
Also i regenerate publish profile but still no luck

```
ErrorUnable to copy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\Microsoft.NET.Build.Extensions\net461\lib\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll" to "D:\MyProject\MyProject.Web\obj\Release\net461\win7-x86\PubTmp\Out\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll". Access to the path 'D:\MyProject\MyProject.Web\obj\Release\net461\win7-x86\PubTmp\Out\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll' is denied.
```

Comment: Hi, can you publish your web app to Azure successfully now? Feel free to share your latest status with us:-)

Answer (score 1):

> Access to the path
>   'D:\MyProject\MyProject.Web\obj\Release\net461\win7-x86\PubTmp\Out\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll'
>   is denied.

According to this error message, this may involved many factors. We could not give you the directly answer to help solve this, but can share my troubleshoot solution to you. Here has some ways can for you troubleshooting. You can try with these.

(1) **Delete** the `.vs` , `obj` and `bin` file at same. And then, **restart** the VS2019 as the administrator role. Try to rebuild the project.

(2) If the above method does not work, please located to the properties of the issue file, check it permission and DO NOT let **Read-only** enabled.

Hope these way could help you.